# Why the link show more/less open all at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

To be brief,
I have 3 links **show more/less**, when i click on one of them to show the content, all the other content are opened !
I need to open each content separately when i click on the link.

```js
$(".o-block-global__wysiwyg").addClass("show-more-height");
$('.btn--link').on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).parent().prev($(".o-block-global__wysiwyg")).hasClass("show-more-height")) {
    $(this).text("Afficher moins");
  } else {
    $(this).text("Afficher plus");
  }

  $(".o-block-global__wysiwyg").toggleClass("show-more-height");
});
```

```css
// reduce content height 
.o-block-global__wysiwyg {
  &.show-more-height {
    height: 5rem;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="o-block-global__wysiwyg wysiwyg">
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quasi libero labore aut minima laborum illo aliquid quidem doloremque exercitationem vero praesentium harum, blanditiis quam fuga expedita ipsam, molestiae deleniti.
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="o-block-global__links">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn--link">
            Afficher plus    </a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn--plain btn--primary external-link" title="Plain Primary (nouvelle fenêtre)">
            Plain Primary    <span class="icon-external-link" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share more details. The current sample does not contain any link with the text "show more". Also, what have you tried to resolve your problem?

Comment: i updated the post to add the link. i tried the js above, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the html for `.btn--link` to know where it sits in context to the element it is toggling, but judging from the other lines, you should change this line:

```
$(".o-block-global__wysiwyg").toggleClass("show-more-height");
```

to

```
$(this).parent().prev($(".o-block-global__wysiwyg")).toggleClass("show-more-height");
```

At the moment, it's toggling all elements with the same class instead of the one you want to toggle.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/martincarlin87/pen/QWdJbqj

Comment: thanks, added a codepen link to my answer which seems to work?

Comment: Thanks, that work with `$(this).parent().prev($(".o-block-global__wysiwyg")).toggleClass("show-more-height");`

Comment: Your example in the codepen will not work when you have many content+link, and that was my problem since the beginning :)

Comment: Ah - I forgot to include my fix when copying the code from the question. Updated with multiple content + links and fix from the answer above.